# Navigate from loginUC UserControl to dashboard page in C# WPF using 'frame' after success log in

Tags: c#, wpf, events, wpf-controls

when the app start up it loads 'MainWindow.xaml'. The mainWindow have a frame

```
<!--MainWindow.xaml-->
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <Frame x:Name="Mainframe" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Background="White" NavigationUIVisibility="Visible">
            </Frame>
        </StackPanel>
```

code behind is

```
 public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        LogInPage loginPage;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            loginPage = new LogInPage();
            Mainframe.Content = new LogInPage();

            LoginUC loginUC = new LoginUC();
            //The event
            loginUC.OnNavigateToDashboard += LoginUC_OnNavigateToDashboard;
        }

        private void LoginUC_OnNavigateToDashboard(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This event is not Called 
            Mainframe.Content = new Dashboard();
        }
    }
```

LogInPage have LoginUC and RegisterUC as UserControls

```
public partial class LogInPage : Page
    {
        LoginUC loginUC;
        RegisterUC registerUC;
 
        public LogInPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loginUC = new LoginUC();
            registerUC = new RegisterUC();

            mainStackPanel.Children.Clear();
            mainStackPanel.Children.Add(loginUC);
            loginUC.RegisterClickEvent += LoginUCEvent_RegisterClickEvent;
            registerUC.LogInClickEvent += RegisterUC_LogInClickEvent;
        }

        private void RegisterUC_LogInClickEvent(object s, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mainStackPanel.Children.Clear();
            mainStackPanel.Children.Add(loginUC);
        }

        private void LoginUCEvent_RegisterClickEvent(object s, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mainStackPanel.Children.Clear();
            mainStackPanel.Children.Add(registerUC);
        }
    }
```

when the user login is successful i want the  'Mainframe.Content' to load Dashboard contents

```
public partial class LoginUC : UserControl
    {
        public delegate void OnRegisterEventClick(object s, RoutedEventArgs e);
        public event OnRegisterEventClick RegisterClickEvent;

        //on successful login navigate to DashBoard
        public event EventHandler OnNavigateToDashboard;
        //simulating data coming from database in this case "password"
        string password = "0000";

        public LoginUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            emailTextBox.Text = "melvin@example.com";
            passwordTextBox.Password = "0000";
        }
        private async void LogInButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            logInButton.IsEnabled = false;
            string UIemail = emailTextBox.Text;
            string UIpassword = passwordTextBox.Password.ToString();

            if (UIpassword==this.password)
            {
                message.Text = "You are logged In!!";
                //The event
                OnNavigateToDashboard?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                logInButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                 logInButton.IsEnabled = true; message.Text = "Wrong Password!!";
            }
       
        }
        private void Register_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => RegisterClickEvent?.Invoke(sender, e);
```

I tried instantiating 'MainWindow' in LoginUC, by creating a public field in public partial class MainWindow:Window `public Frame mainwindowFrame => Mainframe;` and called it from loginUC

```
 private async void LogInButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            logInButton.IsEnabled = false;
            string UIemail = emailTextBox.Text;
            string UIpassword = passwordTextBox.Password.ToString();

            if (passwordTextBox.Password==this.password)
            {
                errormessage.Text = "You are logged In!!";

                MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                mainWindow.Mainframe.Content = new Dashboard();
                logInButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else{logInButton.IsEnabled = true; errormessage.Text = "Wrong Password!!";}
            
        }
```

Comment: You could try an approach like this https://github.com/AndyONeill/LoginNavigation